# How can I plot a set of data in which each subset has three elements

Tags: plotting, functions, data

> let's assume this the set of data
> {{a1,b1,c1},{a2,b2,c2}........{a10,b10,c10}}
> plot a vs b and a vs c
> I have tried plotting this using ListLinePlot function  but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code (not an image) that you have tried. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

> {{a1,b1,c1},{a2,b2,c2}........{a10,b10,c10}} plot a vs b and a vs c

so take `{{an, bn}}` and `{{an, cn}}` out.

> I have tried plotting this using [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html)

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {9, 8, 7}, {3, 4, 7}, {9, 5, 4}};
p1= data[[All,{1,2}]] // ListLinePlot;
p2= data[[All,{1,3}]] // ListLinePlot;
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create some data for fun

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {9, 8, 7}, {3, 4, 7}, {9, 5, 4}};
```

Using the following we can isolate the elements of the first, second, and third slots. You want to look up in the documentation the [**`Part`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) command

```
aset = data[[1 ;;, 1]]
bset = data[[1 ;;, 2]]
cset = data[[1 ;;, 3]]
```

And now you can just plot the subset against each other

```
GraphicsRow@{ListPlot[Thread@{aset, bset}], 
  ListPlot[Thread@{aset, cset}]}
```

> [image: row]